# How to deduce analytical solution from numerical solution

Tags: numerics, integral-transforms

I came across one such integral in my calculations, for which there is no analytical solution. But it exists numerical solution, so how can I derive analytical solution of this integral from numerical solution? Below is my attempt, it might take some time to run the calculation.

```
Clear["`*"]
$Assumptions = {{\[Alpha], \[Beta]} \[Element] Reals};
R[r_] = Exp[-(1/\[Alpha])*((r/\[Beta])^\[Alpha] - 3)];
RR[r_] = Integrate[R[r]*r^2, {r, 0, r}];
Table[{\[Alpha]1, 
  RR[r] /. \[Alpha] -> \[Alpha]1}, {\[Alpha]1, {0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 
   0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19}}]
```

Thanks a lot for everyone's suggestions and help!

Answer (score 3):

1. The integration limit `{r,0,r}` in your integral is a syntactic error. You should write `{r,0,r1}` and then do with `r1` what you need.
2. It is impossible to solve your integral numerically since you did not fix [Beta].
3. However, after correction of the first error the integral can be solved exactly:

   `R[r_] = Exp[-(1/\[Alpha])*((r/\[Beta])^\[Alpha] - 3)];`

   ```
    ` Integrate[R[r]*r^2, {r, 0, r1}, 
     Assumptions -> {\[Alpha] > 0, \[Beta] > 0}]`
   ```

with the effect:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: In fact, you can use the same symbol as the integrating variable and the upper limit, e.g. `Integrate[x, {x, 0, x}]` gives `x^2/2` as "expected" without any syntax error.

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch Thanks a lot for your help, putting the assumptions in the integral grammar solved the problem. This is the first problem I have encountered. The second is how to achieve the integration of this result again to get the analytical solution? A simple example would be adding the following integral ```Integrate[RR[r]^2/r, {r, 0, r1}]``` to the above result. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Domen Thanks for your help. I tried your hint and using ```{x,0,x}``` seems to get the result too, but it seems to benefit from putting assumptions inside the integral grammar, only for this problem of me. I updated my next question in a previous comment. I would appreciate it if you have suggestions as well.

Comment: @little star The second integral, `Integrate[RR[r]^2/r, {r, 0, r1}]`, does not converge. C.f. `Simplify[
 Series[R[r]^2/r, {r, 0, 1}] // Normal, {\[Alpha] > 0, \[Beta] > 0}]`. It diverges as `1/r`  at `r->0`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I might have made a mistake, the integration expression should be ```Integrate[RR[r]/r^2, {r, 0, r1}]```. For this integral expression, once $\alpha=0.13$ is fixed, the integral seems to have a corresponding numerical solution (```Integrate[RR[r]/r^2 /. {\[Alpha] -> 0.13}, {r, 0, r1}]```). So, if $\alpha$ is sufficiently multiple, for example $\alpha=0.1,0.11,0.12,0.13...$, can the exact solution be derived from the numerical solution?

Comment: @little star  This integral diverges even faster. The check is the same as in my previous comment.